# Math formula for populating a grid with boxes

Tags: java, math

I asked this earlier and had a few cool responses but they didn't turn out to work in the end as far as I can tell and I'm fishing around for more ideas. I know NOTHING about math so its worth me throwing this out to you guys and you might enjoy the problem....

I have a 2D grid of boxes. The grid can go 4 boxes wide and infinite boxes deep, but the box fills width-wise first and we only want it to be as deep as it has to be.

For a number n of boxes in the grid, how many boxes deep does the grid need to be?

Some people suggested that I use

```
gridDepth = (numberOfBoxes+4)/4
```

However I'll show you the problem it causes.........

2 boxes is fine

[image]

3 boxes we suddenly leap down and have an unused row

[image]

6 boxes we're looking better again

[image]

But then back to jumping to the next row prematurely.......

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this? My code right now is:

```
Integer totalHeight = (roundUp(imageURLs.size(),4))*200;


//System.out.println(imageURLs.size());
//System.out.println(totalHeight);

// height = numberofentries / 4 rounded up to the nearest multiple of 4

// height = numberofentries rounded up to the nearest 4, divided by 4, times 300px

//Double heightMath= 200*((Math.ceil(Math.abs(imageURLs.size()/4.0))));

//Long heightMath= 300*(long)Math.floor(imageURLs.size() + 1d);

//Integer totalHeight = (int) (double) heightMath;

//if (totalHeight < 300){ 
//      totalHeight = 300; 
//  }

BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(
                               600, totalHeight, //work these out
                               BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics g = result.getGraphics();

Integer x = 0;
Integer y = 0;
Integer w = 150;
Integer h = 200;

for(String imageURL :  imageURLs){

    URL url = new URL(imageURL);

        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(url);
        g.drawImage(bi, x, y, w, h, null);
        x += 150;
        if(x >= result.getWidth()){
            x = 0;
            y += 200;


        }

          ImageIO.write(result,"png",new File("C:\\Users\\J\\Desktop\\resultimage.png"));
    }
}

    private static int roundUp(int numToRound, int multiple) {
    return (numToRound+multiple) / multiple;
}

}
```

I spend a bit longer trying to use the following sort of stuff, but can't get anything decent to work:

```
Double heightMath= 200*((Math.ceil(Math.abs(imageURLs.size()/4.0))));

//Long heightMath= 300*(long)Math.floor(imageURLs.size() + 1d);

Integer totalHeight = (int) (double) heightMath;

double doubleimage = imageURLs.size();

if ((doubleimage/4) == imageURLs.size()/4){
      totalHeight = totalHeight-200;
  }

//if (totalHeight < 300){ 
//      totalHeight = 300; 
//  }

BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(
                               600, totalHeight, //work these out
                               BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics g = result.getGraphics();

Integer x = 0;
Integer y = 0;
Integer w = 150;
Integer h = 200;


for(String imageURL :  imageURLs){

    URL url = new URL(imageURL);

        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(url);
        g.drawImage(bi, x, y, w, h, null);
        x += 150;
        if(x >= result.getWidth()){
            x = 0;
            y += 200;


        }

          ImageIO.write(result,"png",new File("C:\\Users\\J\\Desktop\\resultimage.png"));
    }
}

    private static int roundUp(int numToRound, int multiple) {
    return (numToRound+multiple) / multiple;
}
```

Thanks for reading :)

Trying your suggestion :

```
 int numberOfBoxes = imageURLs.size();
     int totalHeight = gridFix(numberOfBoxes);

private static int gridFix(int numberOfBoxes) {
     int gridDepth = (int) Math.ceil(((double)numberOfBoxes)/4);
     return gridDepth;
}
```

2nd one

```
int gridDepth = (int) Math.ceil(((double)numberOfBoxes)/4);

       int totalHeight = roundUp(gridDepth, 4);

private static int roundUp(int gridDepth, int multiple) {
    return (gridDepth+multiple) / multiple;
}
```

I know i've got them wrong I really can't follow this very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct formula would be:

```
gridDepth = (int) Math.ceil(((double)numberOfBoxes)/4);
```

Use this inside the method roundUp

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling a bit, I tried `int gridDepth = (int) Math.ceil(((double)numberOfBoxes)/4);` and I tried `int numberOfBoxes = imageURLs.size(); int totalHeight = gridFix(numberOfBoxes); private static int roundUp(int gridDepth, int multiple) {
    return (gridDepth+multiple) / multiple;` I'll rewrite these in my original post so you can see how I'm failing to understand

Comment: i'm not sure how to combine it with roundUp(). nothing seems to work. i have straight  `int totalHeight = ((int) Math.ceil(((double)numberOfBoxes)/4))*200;` which works great however it still gives an additional row when on the 4th column. maybe its to do with the other code, ill keep trying.
I really want something extra ontop of it like "if totalheight is exactly divisible by 4 then -1 its grids...maybe

Comment: BECAUSE I AM A GENIUS IN MATHEMATICS and dont give up, i managed to put a -1 in the correct place and it now works perfectly. `int totalHeight = ((int) Math.ceil(((double)numberOfBoxes-1)/4))*200;` thankyou

Comment: Were you like counting from 0? It would explain the need of that -1, anyway good job!